# How can I filter out the title with key word and it's text column and date column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, text-mining, data-preprocessing

I am currently facing a problem that I can't filter out the title with key word "Afghanistan（阿富汗）" from the title column.

Furthermore, I want to keep the date column and the text column too which their title having key word with "Afghanistan（阿富汗）" in the title column.

Attached picture is my coding and the outcome of date frame.
I am looking forward to having helps from you guys, truly appreciated it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxk8C.jpg)

Comment: Hi, picture is not encouraged  to display your code. Try `dput(fmprc_text)` and paste   in your problem.

Comment: Function `grep`  is helpful in your case.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data, the code you tried and packages you used. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fmprc_text |> filter(title %like% "阿富汗")
```